# How to copy file to a virtual machine on a cloud

Tags: ftp, cloud, virtualhost

I need to transfer files to a virtual machines exist on the cloud of my university and I have both Ubuntu and windows installed on my physical machine.
Which tools should I use for this purpose?

Comment: you could try installing ftp on the VM and on the physical machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could transfer files from the Linux machine from terminal via `scp` to the virtual machine.

A starter guide regarding SSH & transfering files can be found [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/TransferFiles).

Basic synthax:

```
scp /path/to/local/file username@some.ip.address.here:/remote/path
```